# How can I tell if a value in Request.Form is a number? (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, string-parsing, request.form

Suppose I must call a function with the following signature:
    doStuff(Int32?)

I want to pass to `doStuff` a value that is read from `Request.Form`.  However, if the value passed in is blank, missing, or not a number, I want `doStuff` to be passed a null argument.  This should not result in a error; it is a operation.

I have to do this with eight such values, so I would like to know what is an elegent way to write in C#

```
var foo = Request.Form["foo"];
if (foo is a number)
    doStuff(foo);
else
    doStuff(null);
```

Comment: Do you need to check for int, decimals etc? What does count as a number?

Comment: In the example I cited, it needs to be an `Int32`, but this question applies to different numeric types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check whether or not it's an integer, try parsing it:

```
int value;
if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["foo"], out value)) {
    // it's a number use the variable 'value'
} else {
    // not a number
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like

```
int dummy;
if (int.TryParse(foo, out dummy)) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

e.g:

```
var foo = Request.Form["foo"]; 
int fooInt = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(foo, out fooInt ))     
    doStuff(fooInt); 
else     
    doStuff(null);
```